# Running debian packages in Scala

Tags: java, scala

Currently, I am running Linux Ubuntu 14.10 and whenever I have to install debian packages I use this command `sudo dpkg-deb -X abc.deb /` and after this I run jar file normally using `sudo nohup java -jar abc.jar &` which starts this jar file in the background.So what my requirement is that I have to do both things in Scala, i.e first my scala program should install debian package and then run jar file.I tried using `Runtime.getRuntime.exec` but its not working.Is there any other way around..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by:

```
import sys.process._
"echo myPassword | sudo -S dpkg-deb -X abc.deb" !
"nohup java -jar abc.jar &" !
```

You can see some more examples [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-execute-exec-external-system-commands-in-scala)

Comment: I tried this one but thing is when I run `sudo dpkg-deb -X abc.deb` through terminal it asks for password, so how can i provide same programatically

Comment: You can set the sudoer user to run commands without having to use a password.

Comment: You can check [this](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/unix/ubuntu_sudo_without_password) out

Comment: I followed other approach, I created 1 shell script and kept both commands into the file and executed it using scala, its working fine now..thanks for ur help..